# Object not found error when deploying via AWS OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services

I get the following error when deploying an app to AWS OpsWorks

```
"HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: /reports/nodes/instancex.localdomain/runs"
```

what does it mean?

Comment: I get the same thing. I'm not sure why this is happening, and if there are more detailed deployment reports, I'd sure like to see them.